# Iterate through a newly generated list: Python

Tags: python

I am trying to reuse the newly created list from the Fibonacci sequence, I want to be able to use the answer to iterate through and call just the even numbers.
I can do this on it's own but have no idea how to use the results of my current code.
Any help greatly appreciated. Thank You.

```
FibStart = int(raw_input('Enter a start number : '))
FibStop = int(raw_input('Enter a stop number : '))
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)        
print map(fib, range(FibStart, FibStop))


# when called will return [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]
```

Comment: As a side note, this is about as inefficient a fibonacci generator as you can get. Besides the doubly-recursive implementation of `fib` itself, you're also calling it separately on each number in the range.

Comment: Oops, didn't realize you planned to help OP in addition to the note on efficiency, great answer btw.

Comment: like, `[i for i in map(fib, range(FibStart, FibStop)) if i % 2 == 0]`? *Disclaimer, this code snippet is totally untested.* the `i % 2 == 0` should filter out non-even numbers, returning just a list of even results.

Comment: @Marius: Yes, because if he tries to test this with anything much bigger than his current values, and it spins for minutes without responding, he's going to get frustrated. Better to know that's going to happen in advance than to be surprised.

Comment: Thank you all for the feed back, I am very new to python and all your help is greatly appreciated, ThorSummoner..your your code worked perfectly thanks.

Comment: Thanks abarnert, worked great, is there any way of making the code more efficient, I have been reading up on recursion, still have a very long way to go, thanks again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just translate your English text into code:

> I want to be able to use the answer

So store it in a variable:

```
answer = map(fib, range(FibStart, FibStop))
```

> … to iterate through

So iterate through it:

```
for value in answer:
```

> … and call just the even numbers.

So check if they're even:

```
    if value % 2 == 0:
```

Or, if you want to make a new list of just the even values to use repeatedly, you can use a list comprehension:

```
evens = [value for value in answer if value % 2 == 0]
for even in evens:
```